# Opening Wordpad and a specific file in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to open Wordpad and a specific file in VB.

I cant figure out how to get to the right path. It work if there is no spaces in the file path (error image).

[image]

**The correct path for testing** C:\Users\James\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DSAinstaller\DSAinstaller\bin\Debug\Dragon

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Dim OpenFile As String = " " & Application.StartupPath & "\" & curItem & "\Inst.rtf"
        'Shell("C:\Windows\write.exe" & " " & Application.StartupPath & "\" & curItem & "\Inst.rtf")
        Shell("C:\Windows\write.exe" & OpenFile)
        'MsgBox(OpenFile)
    Else
        MsgBox("Please select a program first")
    End If
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add quotes to the path if it includes spaces:

```
Dim OpenFile As String = " """ & Application.StartupPath & "\" & curItem & "\Inst.rtf"""
```

Comment: thanks Teddy, i swear i tried that. But it works THANKS

Comment: No problem! vb can be weird with quotes in strings. My favorite is the way a single double quote is typed as `""""` !

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Path.Combine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Dim OpenFile As String = Chr(34) & Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, curItem, "Inst.rtf") & Chr(34)
Process.Start("c:\windows\write.exe", OpenFile)
```

Shell() and MsgBox() are legacy functions that generally shouldn't be used in VB.Net.